# How to subtract n number of days from specific date in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to figure out a way to subtract n number of days from a specific date (not the current date) in Redshift SQL. There are a lot of tutorials on the web about subtracting or adding n number of days from today, but I couldn't find resources for when the source date is not today.

For example, `date(qqr.date_created) >= '2020-06-08' - '45 days' :: interval` doesn't work as Redshift throws an error around the `2020-06-08` datestamp. A format like `date(qqr.date_created) >= date(getdate()) - '45 days' :: interval` would work but it's not what I want, because I am not trying to get "45 days before today", I am trying to get "45 days before the date I specified".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
'2020-06-08'::date - interval '45 day'
```

This converts to a date and then subtracts the days.

If the number of days is not strictly constant, you can use arithmetic:

```
'2020-06-08'::date - 45 * interval '1 day'
```